# Quickblox Q-municate in eclipse ide

Tags: android, eclipse

I have downloaded Quickblox Q-municate from the github,

https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android

and trying to import it into eclipse ide using,

Go to menu File - New - Project. Select Android Project from Existing Code and Browse to your project-directory, click Finish.

But it says two main activities and not able to import all projects. Without selecting one main it proceeds but the project is not building.
I have checked their help but not able to find any details about it.

Can anybody tell me the steps to import and run the project in eclipse ide?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quickblox Q-municate project is build in gradle. you can use [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)
for importing the project.

Comment: yes, quickblox all projects are build with andriod studio but they have mentioned that you can use eclipse ide as well.Our current development is in eclipse only..so if you can help with eclipse that will be great.

Comment: you can use gradle plugins for eclipse. see http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/ or http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-37-43#.VHgVX4eJf3A